# Reverse String Order From stdin

Tags: c, memory

At the terminal, Im able to type

```
line 
line 2
line 3 (when i press ctrl +d, i should get back...
line 3
line 2
line)
```

But all I get is

```
line 3
line 3
line 3
```

```
 int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Stack *the_stack;
  char *line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  ssize_t read;

// check size is mentioned
  if (argc < 2) {
    // print usage
    printf("Usage: %s <Stack size>\n", argv[0]);
    return -1; //return
  }
  // get size
  int size = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

  // Create a stack to hold our test data
  the_stack = create(size); 

while((read = getline(&line, &len, stdin))!=-1){
    if (read > 0){
      for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(line) / sizeof(char *)); i++){
        push(the_stack, line);
        peek(the_stack);
      }
    }
  }
  
  while (!isempty(the_stack)) {
    char *element = (char *) pop(the_stack);
    printf("%s", element);
  }
  free (line);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like there are some important undisclosed functions. Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also note that `sizeof(line)` is not the size of what is pointed at by `line` but the size of the pointer `line` itself. Do you know what `len` is for?

Comment: I believe is the buffer size

Comment: so i should create an array that allocated the data?

Comment: Are you copying the string onto the stack?  Why do you need the cast on `pop()`?  You're not playing with `void *` values, are you?  Without the `create()`, `push()`, `pop()` and maybe `peek()` functions, there's not much we can help with.  There's a decent chance though that you're not making new copies of the line as you push onto the stack, so each time you read a line, you're overwriting the previous lines because you didn't make a copy of them.  If you do make copies, you'll also have to consider how you release the space.